# ArcGIS files exported using 10.3 gives error when opening in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, file-geodatabase

I received two gdb files that were exported using 10.3.

When opening/ importing to a geodatabase in ArcCatalog 10 I get an error that one file is missing, ArcCatalog continues to open but the geodatabases have all the feature classes and datasets they are supposed to have but there is no data in each feature class, is this an ArcGIS versioning mismatch issue or is the data corrupted?

Comment: If the databases were created in 10.3 you probably wont be able to view the data in 10.0. You can use 'create file geodatabase' geoprocessing tool in 10.3 and specify a version (10) then copy/export to it as normal, so long as the database isn't upgraded it should be readable in previous versions. Either way seek a resupply.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the *exact* error message.